# How do I deploy Cloud Functions while ignoring existing functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, continuous-deployment

Say I have the following four functions in my Firebase projects:

```
openDoor(europe-west1)
closeDoor(europe-west1)
openWindow(europe-west1)
closeWindow(europe-west1)
```

Now, these functions live in two separate Node packages, i.e. one that contains `openDoor` and `closeDoor` and *another one* that contains `openWindow` and `closeWindow`.

### Error

If I try to run `firebase deploy` from the package with the door functions, the following error will be thrown (in non-interactive mode):

```
Error: The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
    openWindow(europe-west1)
    closeWindow(europe-west1)
```

This is a problem because it will cancel any CD workflow that tries to deploy these functions.

#### Force delete

There is an option to **force-delete** any existing functions:

```
  -f, --force              delete Cloud Functions missing from the current 
                           working directory without confirmation
```

However, I want **the opposite**. I want to keep all existing functions.

#### Theoretical workaround

There is one workaround that I found would work in theory, which is:

```bash
yes N | firebase deploy --interactive
```

Piping `N` into the interactive deploy command, which will answer `N` to the deletion prompt:

```
The following functions are found in your project but do not exist in your local source code:
    openWindow(europe-west1)
    closeWindow(europe-west1)

If you are renaming a function or changing its region, it is recommended that you create the new function first before deleting the old one to prevent event loss. For more info, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#modify

? Would you like to proceed with deletion? Selecting no will continue the rest of the deployments. (y/N)
```

The problem now is that I am using https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action to deploy the functions, which means that I need to have a built-in Firebase solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the new [codebases feature in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/organize-functions#organize_functions_in_codebases).

By specifying a `codebase` in your `firebase.json` `functions` configuration, this problem is solved. The Firebase CLI will no longer prompt you to delete other functions as it only considers the functions of the same **`codebase`**.

If your `firebase.json` previously looked like this:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "cloud_functions",
    "ignore": [...],
    "predeploy": [...],
    "postdeploy": [...]
  }
}
```

You only need to add `"codebase": "<name>"` to the config:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "source": "cloud_functions",
    "codebase": "window",
    "ignore": [...],
    "predeploy": [...],
    "postdeploy": [...]
  }
}
```

---

The deploy will now look like this:

```bash
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function window:openWindow(europe-west1)...
i  functions: updating Node.js 16 function window:closeWindow(europe-west1)...
```

Note that the actual function name does *not* change, i.e. the function will still only be called `openWindow` (without the prefix) in the Firebase / Google Cloud Console. So this is basically the perfect solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can also [specify the function names](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions) when performing deployment.

```
firebase deploy --only functions:openDoor,functions:closeDoor
```

Comment: Sure. Just note that this is somewhat of a No-go for CD. If you need to manually adjust CD every time you create or modify a function, you might as well deploy manually.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Before the availability of codebases, this was the approach used. However, you are right in that you wouldn't add this as a build step as-is. You would bring in `firebase-tools` as a module, scan your code for function triggers and then invoke the appropriate deployment. I added this here for the sake of legacy users and anyone who needs a one-off command who stumbles here from a search engine.

Comment: That totally makes sense. However, would you not agree the other answer is the better solution considering the codebases feature was *specifically* added by Firebase for this exact purpose?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot Going forward, codebases is a better solution **if** you can use it. However, it is still a beta API and moving to v2 Cloud Functions has caveats (i.e. no SLA, limited support, limited region availability). As I said, I added this here as an alternate option, for better question SEO, and for legacy/one-off users who can't rely on these beta APIs. It's up to the reader, whether that's you, or future searchers, to choose what they want to implement from the tools available to them.

Comment: Codebases work for v1 Cloud Functions.